# Where is jiffies computed in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm porting 3.14 to an ARM-based SOC which was successfully running the 3.2 kernel.

I'm getting stuck in the code that calibrates jiffies.

calibrate_delay_converge()-init/calibrate.c

```
    /* wait for "start of" clock tick */
    ticks = jiffies;
    while (ticks == jiffies)   <---- infinite loop waiting for jiffies to change
            ; /* nothing */
    /* Go .. */
```

jiffies isn't being updated. Where does jiffies get updated? I'm looking for smoking gun code like jiffies++ or a .S file updating jiffies.

I went down the rabbit hole of the timers and interrupt system in Linux. The timer interrupt isn't enabled (in the PL190 HW). I'm hoping if I can track from the bottom up (where jiffies SHOULD be called), I can find why the interrupt(s) aren't being enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at do_timer(). It was moved to kernel/time/timekeeping.c at some point in the past few years.

jiffies does not directly get incremented, it gets assigned the low order 32-bit of jiffies_64

```
/* 
 * The 64-bit jiffies value is not atomic - you MUST NOT read it 
 * without sampling the sequence number in xtime_lock. 
 * jiffies is defined in the linker script... 
 */ 
void do_timer(unsigned long ticks) 
{ 
 jiffies_64 += ticks; 
 update_wall_time(); 
 calc_global_load(ticks); 
}
```

In 3.2 it is http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?v=3.2#L1192

jiffies gets the value from jiffies_64 here in the machine specific file:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S?v=3.2

```
 36 #ifndef __ARMEB__
 37 jiffies = jiffies_64;
 38 #else
 39 jiffies = jiffies_64 + 4;
 40 #endif
```

Comment: I think do_timer() is the smoking gun. My timer interrupt handler calls clock_event_device.event_handler() which is set to tick_handle_periodic() by clockevents_register_device().  tick_handle_periodic() calls tick_periodic() calls do_timer()

Comment: The second code example is just a linker trick. It's naming the lower 32-bits of jiffies_64 as jiffies.

Comment: Yes. To elaborate for the reader, ARMEB is big-endian, hence the conditional.